# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getDependencyComparator()Ljava/util/Comparator;"}}

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying add spring security to my project. I am using Spring 4 and I would like to use spring security 3.2. I have problem with configuration:
This is my exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getDependencyComparator()Ljava/util/Comparator;
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getDependencyComparator()Ljava/util/Comparator;
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getDependencyComparator()Ljava/util/Comparator;"}}
```

And this is project's dependency tree:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building engineering-project-web Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ engineering-project-web ---
[INFO] com.pawel:engineering-project-web:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.5:runtime
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:runtime
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15:runtime
[INFO] +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.7:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.654 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-01-18T14:38:19+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Upgrade your spring version to one of the newer 4.0.x releases (and I would suggest also using the newest Spring Security 3.2.x version).

Comment: In addition you have a mix of Spring versions at the runtime. Sure tu run your JVM with `-verbose` to see the path for classes. Even if SS 3.2 is compatible with SF 4.0, you CP may have older version. So, it is an impact for the classloader

Comment: I was trying the SF 3.2 and 4.2.5 but the same error.

Answer (score 7):

I got this error while configuring Spring based Web Application in Tomcat7 (using Maven).
This problem basically exists because of dependency incompatibility. I was using Spring 4.1.6 along with Spring-Security 3.2.x.

But by changing Spring-Security version to 4.0.0, I was able to fix the issue.
Hope this helps....

Comment: How about for Tomcat8 ?